# Laravel 5 - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::Paginate()

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I'm having an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::Paginate()

I've been doing this:

```
public function index ()
{

    $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->get()->paginate(5);
    $articlesLink = $articles->render();

    return view('articles.index', compact('articles', 'articlesLink'));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try changing

```
$articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->get()->paginate(5);
```

to

```
$articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->paginate(5);
```

By calling `->get()`, you'd be getting a `Collection` object back, and there is no `paginate()` method in the `Collection` object, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, that work perfectly when I've remove the get()

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index () {

  // you =>  $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->get()->paginate(5);
 // me => $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->latest()->paginate(5);
    // Unnecessary  $articlesLink = $articles->render();

    return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));
 }
```

Comment: could you add an explanation of what your code is doing and how it fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

please remove get() from the query.

Comment: This has already been given as a solution (and explained, too) in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37896671/10871073).